# getElementById not working for XML in IE

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have xmlDoc which is similar to DOM structure.

```
<Template>
<Function>
   <parameter id="prm_1_1_1"></parameter>
</Function>
</Template>
```

When I use xmlDoc.getElementById('prm_1_1_1'), it works nicely in chrome and returns xml node but gives `undefined` in IE11.

xmlDoc.querySelector('prm_1_1_1') also returns `undefined` in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querySelector() along with attribute selector

```js
var string = '<Template><Function><parameter id="prm_1_1_1"></parameter></Function></Template>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(string);

console.log('doc', xmlDoc);
r1.innerHTML = 'Doc: ' + xmlDoc;

var idle = xmlDoc.getElementById('prm_1_1_1');
r2.innerHTML = 'By Id: ' + idle;
console.log('id', idle);

var attrel = xmlDoc.querySelector('[id="prm_1_1_1"]');
r3.innerHTML = 'By Attr: ' + attrel;
console.log('attr', attrel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="r1"></div>
<div id="r2"></div>
<div id="r3"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rc1zxgvu/)

Comment: Knowing why this works and not `getElementById` would be an interesting addition to your answer :)